# Using JMeter i can open firefox Driver config, but WebDriver sampler code is not working

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

Using JMeter i can open firefox Driver config, but WebDriver sample code is not working.

Below is the code used in WebDriver sample, Please help me.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything suspicious in *jmeter.log* file? My expectation is that you're using the latest Firefox version and WebDriver Sampler plugin doesn't support it.

As per [JMeter Plugins Changelog](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Changelog/)

> bump up Selenium dependency to 2.47.0

As per [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

> v2.47.0
>
> =======
>
> - Supports native events for Firefox version 31 (immediately previous ESR).
>   Native event support has been discontinued for versions of Firefox later
>   than 33. Synthetic events tested on Firefox versions 31 (immediately
>   previous ESR), 38 (immediately previous release and current ESR), and 39
>   (current release).

I would suggest downgrading your Firefox to version 31.0.6 . You can get it from [Mozilla FTP website](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/31.0/)

Also check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide, it covers this and several other frequent problems.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dmitri T. The version 31.0.6 was the last version supporting native events.  the Browser.get call is native I think.  You can use a later version of firefox if you navigate instead using a JavascriptExecutor , and avoid the native calls, like .get and .sendKeys.